# How to put the row count of query into a variable before I return that query in ref_cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm building a query to be used in pagination, so my query looks like this:

```
open ref_cursor for
select * from TableA ta
join TableB tb on ta.id = tb.ta_id
where ta.conditionA = "searchParameter1"
where tb.conditionB = "searchParameter2"
order by ta.columnF
offset i_row_offset rows
fetch next i_row_fetch rows only
```

I would like to return this part as output parameter, before I offset/fetch the query results:

```
// I would like to get the row count of this part...
o_all_row_count := select count(*) from TableA ta
                    join TableB tb on ta.id = tb.ta_id
                    where ta.conditionA = "searchParameter1"
                    where tb.conditionB = "searchParameter2"

// And then slice if by offset/fetch only the rows that I want
select * from TableA ta
join TableB tb on ta.id = tb.ta_id
where ta.conditionA = "searchParameter1"
where tb.conditionB = "searchParameter2"
order by ta.columnF
offset i_row_offset rows
fetch next i_row_fetch rows only
```

I can definitely do this, but this looks like I'm gonna execute twice the same searching query. How do I do this better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can; in order to find out how many rows are there in a cursor, you have to fetch from it and yes - that's doing the same job twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want, just not directly nor easily. What you need is to expand the cursor by a column. You then populate that column with the analytic version of count building a single partition:

```
select ...
     , count(*) over() "rows in cursor"
  from tablea  a 
  join tableb  b
    on ( ... ) 
 where ...;
```

This will in all likelihood also require you to actually specify your columns in the select **(i.e. no select * )** and the subsequent fetch. See full [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6e98f56f9df9c05cdaaa91694a30fa8).

Since I only use upper case to draw attention you can basically ignore everything except the upper case variables and the generated column in the open cursor select.

The question becomes: Is it worth the effort?

---

BTW your query

```
select * from TableA ta
join TableB tb on ta.id = tb.ta_id
where ta.conditionA = "searchParameter1"
where tb.conditionB = "searchParameter2"
```

is invalid. First off you can only have at most 1 WHERE clause per SELECT. Secondly, double quoting causes the value quoted to be interpreted as a variable name NOT a string constant. For value you need a single quote. The above should be:

```
select * 
from TableA ta
join TableB tb on ta.id = tb.ta_id
where ta.conditionA = 'searchParameter1'
  and tb.conditionB = 'searchParameter2'
...
```